# Expectation Notation Difference

Tags: notation, expected-value, economics

I have a very short question regarding the notation of an expectation term.

So in macroeconomics there is the Euler equation:

$$C^{-\sigma}_t=E_t\beta C^{-\sigma}_{t+1}(1+i_t)/(1+\pi_{t+1})$$

My question is now, would it be wrong if I notate it as follows:
$$C^{-\sigma}_t=\beta E_tC^{-\sigma}_{t+1}(1+i_t)/(1+\pi_{t+1}).$$

Since $\beta$ is a constant and is not connoted with any uncertainty my guess would be that the two expressions above are actually the same and both notations would be correct.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Expectations are in general linear, meaning that for two integrable random variables $X$, $Y$ and constants $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, we have $\mathbb{E}(aX+bY)=a\mathbb{E}(X) + b\mathbb{E}(Y).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption that the two terms are equivalent is correct. This property is called the linearity of the expectation.
For a constant $a$ and two random variables $X,Y$ we have $E[aX] = aE[X]$ and $E[X+Y] = E[X]+E[Y]$.
See the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) for more.